# Custom build task not showing in YAML task list

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

We wrote a custom Azure DevOps build task, but we can't find it in the YAML editor task list. It doesn't even show up in search.

This is my `task.json`:

```
{
  "id": "17813657-13c6-4cd8-b245-8d8b3b0cf210",
  "name": "ApplitoolsBuildTask",
  "friendlyName": "Applitools Build Task",
  "description": "Add the Applitools dashboard as a tab in the Azure DevOps build results page.",
  "categories": [ "Build" ],
  "category": "Build",
  "author": "Applitools",
  "version": {
      "Major": 0,
      "Minor": 44,
      "Patch": 0
  },
  "instanceNameFormat": "Applitools Build Task $(version)",
  "execution": {
      "Node": {
          "target": "dist/index.js"
      }
  }
}
```

I also tried with only `categories` property, and it still didn't show in the search.

I then tried downloading Augurk locally and examined its content (also available in GitHub: https://github.com/Augurk/vsts-extension/tree/master/src), and I saw in AugurkCLI it doesn't even have `categories` property, as it has a typo: `categorues`, and for some reason it still shows up. This leads me to think there's no relation between that property and the task list.

I also tried examining the XML file and saw it has `<PublisherDetails>` section, which my .vsix file doesn't have. What should I put in my `vss-extension.json` file to have it? And will it help getting my extension to show up in the Task List?

Note that in the Classic editor (the one with the UI) I see it just fine, in the right categories (if I have the "category" property), and if I don't have it then it still shows up when I search. The problem I have is to get my build-task to show up in the YAML editing Task List.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, our team is fixing this issues now. The issue caused by the YAML assistant panel doesn't allow tasks without input parameters. But worked in classic editor.

Before our fixed release deployed, you can use this **workaround** to achieve your customize task appeared in the YAML editor task list:

> Change your script to accept an input parameter. And then the task will appeared in YAML editor task list.

You can reference this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/549068/yaml-assistant-panel-doesnt-show-tasks-with-no-inp.html) we received recently. We will inform you here once we deployed the fixed release and the issue be fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to add an hidden input element? Will that help?

Comment: @Itai Bar Haim , in fact, this is a temporary measure which add one dummy parameter in your `.ts` file about this task, but not be used by the body of the function. Yeah, it can help the task displayed in YAML editor task list temporarily. Because as current code, we filtered out some snippets without inputs and are fixing this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it's a bug on Microsoft side. I don't have any input fields in the build task, and the Azure DevOps YAML editor task list filters out any task that doesn't have input fields.

They told me they had fixed it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576169/our-custom-azure-devops-build-task-doesnt-show-in.html

The fix should be available in a few weeks.

Comment: we have been released deployed the fixed code. You can search your custom task in the YAML editor task list now.